# search with suggestion when edditext onchange event in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, onchange

I'm writing a dictionary app for android. I want to fill search data to listview when edditext is typing. It could search but typing speed so slow. Please help me.

```
txtKeyword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String st = txtKeyword.getText().toString().trim();
                lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
                ArrayList<String> list = search(st);
                adapter = new VicnAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                adapter.setListView(list);
                lvData.setAdapter(adapter);
                restartSearch(st);
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use notifyDataSetChanged() fuction of Adapter instead of creating every time new object of Adapter it may be speed up your search

Answer (score 0):

### The problems are:

1. You are calling `findViewById()` every time the `onTextChanged()` is called.
2. You are creating a new `Adapter` every time the `onTextChanged()` is called.

### The solution is:

move these codes to your `onCreate()`

```
lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
adapter = new VicnAdapter(getApplicationContext());
lvData.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and modify your `onTextChanged()` like this

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String st = txtKeyword.getText().toString().trim();
                list.addAll(search(st));
                adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();                    
                restartSearch(st);
           }
```